# Do not wait for a respondse of PHP shell_exec

Tags: php

Is it possible to skip waiting for a response of a shell execution command?

The command executes aria2c and places a file to the download queue. Therefore I do not have to wait for the response. Otherwise I run into a "Internal Server Error" because of max execution time is reached.

Comment: If you have code, you might get better responses by including what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `exec()` and redirect the output to a file or null it will then run in the back ground

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This might work! Just one more question: I tried
`exec($cmd > "log/logfile.txt");`
But this won't work. Can you please tell me, what the root of the output is.

Comment: it will be the home directory, best give an absolute path